# Adding Lucene to Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, lucene, build.gradle

I have problems with adding Lucene 6.2.0 to my Android Studio 2.1.2 project. However, adding this library to IntelliJ IDEA is not a problem. I tried copying Lucene files to my libs folder and then adding jar files listed [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description) as libraries (Right click => Add as library). **Build.gradle** was looking fine:

```
compile files('libs/lucene-6.2.0/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-6.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/lucene-6.2.0/demo/lucene-demo-6.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/lucene-6.2.0/core/lucene-core-6.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/lucene-6.2.0/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-6.2.0.jar')
```

```html
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4150Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: C:\Users\Tomek\AndroidStudioProjects\UniversalSoundboard\app\src\main\java\com\tomaszstankowski\universalsoundboard\adapters\SoundListAdapter.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Tomek\AndroidStudioProjects\UniversalSoundboard\app\src\main\java\com\tomaszstankowski\universalsoundboard\custom\singletons\SoundBank.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:coldswapKickerDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:...while parsing org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar/ArabicAnalyzer.class
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 40.184 secs
Information:5 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Tried adding these libraries as Dependencies from Maven Central but the result was the same as above.

```
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:...while parsing org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar/ArabicAnalyzer.class
```

I also tried this way:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

My app ran without any errors but Lucene classes were not recognized.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be solved now.

```
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
```

Means that library was written in Java 8 (version 52.0) and android API still doesn't support Java 8 strongly enough to use such libraries even if you have selected JDK 1.8+ in your Android Studio project settings. Correct me if I'm wrong.